# Fragrouter error in Ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

If you look at the picture, you'll see these errors. Is there a solution?

[image]

```
~$ fragrouter -B1
fragrouter: sniff_init failed: socket: Operation not permitted
~$ fragrouter -i wlan0 -B1
fragrouter: sniff_init failed: socket: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Try to run it with `sudo`.